# selecting marbles at the same time vs without replacement

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A bag contains 5 red marbles, 9 white marbles, and 6 blue marbles. You draw 4 marbles out at random, can we say selecting marbles without replacement is the same as selecting marbles at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

I assume without replacement means that the drawn marbles are not put back once drawn. Assuming this, it depends on whether the order in which the marbles are drawn is relevant. If you just want to know probabilities for how many of a color are drawn, then this is indeed equivalent.